# When I try to download something from the software center I keep getting an authentication error how do I fix it

Tags: gnome, openjdk

I am trying to download OpenJDK Java 8 runtime so I can download Minecraft, but I keep getting an

> authentication error

and it says I don't have permission and that I have to delete stuff.

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1157100/edit) your question to provide the complete, exact messages. Including all the details that you don't quite understand. There are many, many possible issues that involve 'authentication error', so it's best to narrow the field with some additional information.